# Why would PHP not always upload a file

Tags: php, redirect, upload

On a PHP page, I call an upload function that contains the standard PHP upload procedure. After I call the function, I do a redirect (tried with either window. location or header ()).

The strange thing is that everything works fine a couple of times, then it would not upload anymore (`uploadOK` won't be 0 either). It would just not move the file onto the server.

Then, I would take out the redirect and the upload would start working again. I put the redirect back in, the upload will still work a couple of times then stop again... Do you have any idea why?

Another strange thing is that, even when it doesn't work, the upload function still returns the correct path+filename, but it would not echo "File ... was uploaded".

I suspect that the problem might be in the move_uploaded_file() function... but it would not return 0, because "Error..." would not be echoed.

Without calling the redirect after the upload, it uploads fine every time.

PHP page:

```
$_SESSION["temp_file_name"]="../".UploadFisier($_FILES["fileToUpload"], $_SESSION["ID_CLASA"]."_".$id_item."_temp_".UserIdLogat($dbocr)."_", "../teme/", "");     
header("Location: trimite_tema_script.php");
```

The Upload function:

```
function UploadFisier($file, $sufix, $target_dir, $maxsize)
{
    if ($maxsize=="") { $maxsize=3000000; }
    if ($target_dir=="") { $target_dir="../upload/"; }

    $target_empty_file=$target_dir.$sufix;
    $target_file = $target_empty_file.basename($file["name"]);

    $uploadOk = 1;


    if ($target_file != $target_empty_file)
    {
        if ($file["size"] > $maxsize)
        {
            echo "file too large";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       echo "no file selectec.";
       $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($uploadOk == 1)
    {
        //we overwrite
        if (file_exists($target_file))
        {
            unlink($target_file);
        }
        if (move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $target_file))
        {
            echo "File ". basename( $file["name"]). " was uploaded.";
            //we output the path and filename without the "../" at the beginning
            $linksave=substr($target_file, 3);
        }
        else
        {
           
            echo "Error....";
        }
    }
    echo "uploadOk ".$uploadOk;
    return $linksave;
}
```

Comment: You need to start by properly analyzing what “not working” actually means.

Comment: FYI, checking if the target file exists and if so, unlinking it, is completely superfluous. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php: _“Warning: If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.”_

Answer (score 0):

Check the file_uploads value in PHP.ini and confirm that is something like this

```
file_uploads = On
```

Comment: It is rather unlikely though that this settings gets switched on and off between different requests …

Comment: May be related to the upload limit size of the server.

Comment: But that is also rather unlikely to change willy-nilly.

Comment: I can upload the same files without a problem if I comment out the redirect..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a try/catch in your code. maybe you will find out more about the error.

```
function UploadFisier($file, $sufix, $target_dir, $maxsize)
{
    try {
       // your code
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
         die();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I will try echo to a <script>alert, because the redirect takes me to another page

Comment: it doesn't work.. window.alert also won't work if I redirect after. All problems gone if I comment out the redirect...both alert and upload work...very strange